# Download MySQL table as a spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

How do you download an sql table as an Excel spreadsheet?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navicat, MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin would all work if you want to create the spreadsheet yourself.

To allow users to download spreadsheets from a website, you can use a library.  Some good options are:

**IIS**: 
EPPlus http://epplus.codeplex.com/ or NPOI http://npoi.codeplex.com/

**Apache**:
PHP Excel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) or Apache POI (http://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Use a SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ... statement to write a CSV file or a tab-delimited file that you can open directly in Excel.

Comment: Thanks. So we can integrate that into a JavaScript button?

Comment: thanks! It worked, is there a way to get the column names as well? I fear going by some other threads that you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Use phpMyAdmin, it has option of exporting thata to multiple formats:
csv,scv for excel, json, doc, latex, wiki table, odf, pdf, sql

Comment: How do you make that happen when the user clicks on a "Download" button?

Answer (score 0):

Use a database client like [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql).

Comment: Thanks, but is there an open source alternative to the same?

Comment: The [MySQL Workbench Community Edition](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench) is open source.